SVD decomposition- vectors of U
I have the following question:
In most literature, authors claim that in SVD decomposition of matrix (i.e. $A=U\Sigma V^T$)  we can easily get the vectors in $U$ by computing eigenvectors of $A*A^T$.
Is that always true? I mean, we need this connection (or we even define vector $u_i$ in such a way) that $u_i=Av_i/||Av_i||$ (of course for $i=1\ldots,rank(A)$). Is that directly satisfied in $U=A*A^T$ or not?
I know that $u_i=Av_i/||Av_i||$ are the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ but what about opposite implication?

I'm having a hard time understanding your question. The columns of $U$ are the left singular vectors of $A$, that is, the eigenectors of $AA^T$.

Yes, but if I understand correctly in SVD decomposition we need to have $u_i=Av_i/||Av_i||$. Do vector from $U$ (obtained as eigenvectors of $AA^T$) satisfy this?

You can always scale an eigenvector.

I know, but if I want to have some specific method to get this decomposition, that means that I have to (or I want to) know upfront that normalized eigenvectors of $AA^T$ will give the right result. If I need to check every time that $u_i=Av_i/||Av_i||$ then for me it doesn't make sense to compute them by $AA^T$.

Given $U$ as eigenvectors of $AA^T$, let $v_i = A^T u_i/|A^T u_i|$. Then you can verify easily that $u_i=Av_i/||Av_i||$

Okay it's pointless honestly... Now you defined $V$ by $A$ and $U$. :) I aim in gaining $V$ and $U$ ONLY by computing eigenvectors of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ respectively.

@fucjuszkon You cannot do that because there may be a lot of ambiguities in the computation of the eigenvectors. For example you can multiply some eigenvectors by $-1$, or you can permute the eigenvalues, or also when there are multiplicities the choice for the basis of the eigenvectors is arbitrary. The only way to get $U$ and $V$ is to compute one of the two and then to generate the other one by multiplying $A$ or $A^T$

Well that's exactly the answer I wanted! Thank you!
